# Why Will This Random Picker Always Pick The Same Choice

Tags: python, random, tkinter

I am learning python and am kind of just messing around with what I could make. As a proof of concept for a bigger project I made a very very simple python scrip which will display One or Two on the GUI, but this doesn't work. The random picker always picks Two and never one. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import*
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title("amazing")

def one():
     label1 = Label(root, text="one", font=("Comic Sans MS", 30),  fg="purple").place(x=100, y=300)


def two():
    label2 = Label(root, text="two", font=("Comic Sans MS", 30),  fg="purple").place(x=100, y=300)


rchoice = [two, one]
doit = random.choice(rchoice)

Button = Button(root, text="Button", width=15, height=3, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), fg="blue", bg="lightgreen", command=doit).pack(pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When do you want it to change: when starting up or when the button is clicked? Also how many times have you run it, with only two options its quite likely to have the same element selected many times in a row with a (pseudo-)random process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your program always runs the same option when the button is clicked is because the label (`one` or `two`) is chosen when the program launches, not each time the button is clicked. So when your program boots up, it'll pick either `one` or `two` and then that button will always run that chosen label (until restarting). Basically `random.choice` is only executed one time at the beginning and then `doit` is set for the duration of the program.

To fix this, you'll want to select the label when the button is clicked. You can do that by redefining `doit` like this:

```
def doit():
    rchoice = [one, two]
    selected = random.choice(rchoice)
    return selected()
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `doit` is not a `function`, but the resulting value of the `random.choice()` that was called *prior to your mainloop*.  So once it settles on either `two` or `one`, it will never change again during your program `doit` is not calling the `random.choice()` function to pick a different one.

You will need to change your `Button`'s `command` argument to this instead:

```
btn = Button(root, text="Button", width=15, height=3, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), fg="blue", bg="lightgreen", command=lamdba: random.choice(rchoice)).pack(pady=50)
```

This allows the `command` to execute the `random.choice()` function each time the `Button` is invoked.

Also it's a terrible idea to overwrite your imported names like `Button`.  Use a different name like `btn`, otherwise you will never be able to create a different `Button` after that point.

Or, just don't use star imports at all:

```
import tkinter as tk
button = tk.Button(...)
```

Comment: Awesome, I dont usually call them "Button" I just quickly wrote this for testing and wasn't really concerned about the name.